# R: Lattice Q-Q Plot with regression Line

Tags: r

I can create a lattice qq-plot with:

```
qqnorm(surfchem.cast$Con)
```

but I have not learned how to add a `panel.abline` or `prepane.qqmathline()`.

I've looked in the lattice graphics book and searched the web without finding the correct syntax. A pointer to how to add this line representing the linear relationship between theoretical and data quantiles will be greatly appreciated. I also do not find a question here where the answer is for a qq plot rather than an xyplot.

Comment: `qqnorm()` is the base R function, so I'm surprised you've gotten it to  work in **lattice**. The closest **lattice** function is `qqmath()`; the second example in `?qqmath` demonstrates the use of both `panel.qqmathline` and `prepanel.qqmathline`. Without a sample data set or some more info about what you've tried, it's hard to give you any help beyond pointing you to that doc.

Comment: Thank you. I probably used the base R function and I'll certainly read ?qqmath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention with Q-Q plots is to plot the line that goes through the first and fourth quartiles of the sample and the test distribution, *not* the line of best fit.

```
set.seed(1)
Z <- rnorm(100)
qqnorm(Z)
qqline(Z,probs=c(0.25,0.75))
```

[image]

The reason for this is that, if your sample is not normally distributed, the deviations tend to be at the extremes.

```
set.seed(1)
Z <- runif(100)   # NOTE: uniform distribution...
qqnorm(Z)
qqline(Z, probs=c(0.25,0.75))
```

[image]

If you want the line connecting the corners, as in your comment, use different probabilities. The reason you need to use (0.01,0.99) rather than (0,1) is that the latter will produce infinities.

```
set.seed(1)
Z <- runif(100)   # NOTE: uniform distribution...
qqnorm(Z)
qqline(Z, probs=c(0.01,0.99))
```

[image]

Comment: I do want the line from lower left corner to upper right corner, not the best fit to the data. Thanks for your response.

Comment: See my edits. Also, it turns out there is a much easier way: the `qqline(...)` function is designed for exactly what you want.